# missing group in ggplot2 display with fill option

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do some basic plot with ggplot but with one dataframe for some unknown reason, i can't see one of my group! does anyone has some idea what is wrong?

```
> dput(head(data2_2020))
structure(list(Year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L
), Id = c("22923", "22928", "22928", "22928", "22928", "22928"
), G_Num = c("Gm 0502-2", "Gm 0502-7", "Gm 0502-7", "Gm 0502-7", 
"Gm 0502-7", "Gm 0502-7"), T_Location = c("Crumley Ranch 1", 
"Crumley Ranch 1", "Crumley Ranch 1", "Crumley Ranch 1", "Crumley Ranch 1", 
"Crumley Ranch 1"), Tot = c(1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Num = c("1", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), RDW = c(2, 4.8, 3.7, 3.5, 4.31, 3.38
), PW = c(24.16, 42.86, 27.87, 27.71, 39.12, 31.02), SD = c(4.23, 
4.87, 4.37, 3.96, 4.91, 5.61), RSD = c(8.1, 8625, 7.59, 8615, 
8415, 8.1), PrWFr2020 = c(34.8, 3.1, 4.3, 3.5, 5.4, 7.7), PrWAll2021 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), X24.juin = c(3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), X01.juil = c(4L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 7L), X09.juil = c(6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L), X22.juil = c(8L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 8L), X03.ao.t = c(13L, 
10L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 12L), X14.ao.t = c(18L, 11L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 
13L), X25.ao.t = c(18L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 15L), X08.sept = c(22L, 
13L, 17L, 18L, 15L, 18L), X28.sept = c(30L, 14L, 15L, 19L, 13L, 
18L), feuilles9.06 = c(8L, 10L, 5L, 13L, 12L, 5L), feuilles21.06 = c("16", 
"16", "12", "20", "19", "13"), feuilles12.07 = c(26L, 23L, 20L, 
28L, 30L, 23L), feuilles3.08 = c(33L, 26L, 26L, 31L, 38L, 30L
), feuilles19.08 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Control", "V. berlandieri"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")


  ggplot(data2_2020, aes(x = reorder(Id,PrWFr2020), y = PrWFr2020, group = Type, fill = as.factor(Type))) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge", width = 1)+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("firebrick","steelblue"),name= "Plant origin :",labels=c("Controls",expression(italic("V. berlandieri"))))+
    xlab("Genotypes")+
    ylim(0,15)+
    ylab("Poids des bois de taille")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),plot.title = element_text(size = 8))+
    ggtitle("Poids de bois de taille des génotypes en 2020")
```

[image]

the 2 groups seems to be well identified then i don't understand what is wrong?
it works perfectly well with other dataframe .. i checked and i'm supposed to have 15 type "control"
thanks for your help !

Comment: Try using alpha inside `geom_col()`

Comment: Unfortunately your example data contains only one group. One issue could be that because of `ylim(0, 15)` values get dropped which fall outside of the limits. Hence first thing I would try is to remove `ylim`.

Comment: thanks stefan ! so easy and obvious  i didn't think about it ! works perfectly now!